# Blueimp jQuery Upload Progress - straight to 100%

Tags: jquery, file-upload, progress-bar, blueimp

I am following the [basic plus](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) demo, almost to the tee, and cannot get the progress bar to work correctly. That `console.log` below returns 100% on upload button click.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true,
        formData:function(form){
            //get file name
            var $this = this;
            var formSelector = 'form-' + $($this.files)[0].name.replace(/\W/g,'-');
            return $('.'+formSelector).serializeArray();
        },
        progressall:function(e,data){
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css( 'width', progress + '%');
            console.log(progress);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress was going to 100% immediately because it was uploading that fast. When I uploaded a larger file progress was seen to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that true!
When i try to upload a small file the progressbar blows to 100% but from Chrome console the request is still in **(pending)** state that's the upload is still running!

Comment: I wonder if the solution to this post explains the situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691236/large-gap-between-last-file-progress-hitting-100-and-the-stop-done-events