# blueimp Jquery upload plugin : Large gap between last file progress hitting 100% and the done event

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, progress-bar, blueimp

all people are asking the same questions no no answer anywhere in all threads and forums.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dropZone: $("#dragandrop"),
    pasteZone: $("#dragandrop"),
    //singleFileUploads: false,
    //progressInterval:50,
    //bitrateInterval:500,
    //forceIframeTransport: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.submit();
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
            //if (data.loaded == data.total ) {
            //    if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var progress = parseInt(data._progress.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            console.log(data.loaded + " " + data.total + " " + data.bitrate);
            $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        //}
    },
    always: function (e, data) {
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width',0);
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        var result = data.result.data;
        //add the flash success message
        $('#trust-center-flash-message').html(result.message);
        //add the new images to the preview
        previewImages(result.attachments);
        return alert("done");
    }
});
```

I tried all the solutions on the internet. 
I'm not using the plugin back-end php class.

Comment: I found that this gap caused because of my backend. but still, is there anyway  to make it works when the backend finished ?

Comment: Please check my solution/workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461810/2277301

Answer (score 1):

As [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/) [says it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691236/large-gap-between-last-file-progress-hitting-100-and-the-stop-done-events/14691449#14691449), and as you mentions yourself:

> The progress event only tracks the progress of the upload, not the
>   progress of the request.

One way to solve this problem is to update how we respond to the progress event.

> One solution would be to have your progress bar stop at say, 90% then
>   bump it to 100% in the done callback. simply multiply data.total by
>   1.1
>
> ```
>     progress: function (e, data) {
>         var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / (data.total*1.1) * 100, 10);
>         var bar = data.context.children().children(".progress");
>         $(bar).css("width", progress + "%");
>     },
> ```

You could also do this for the event "progressall" depending on which one you want to modify.

For all the callbacks [see the API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options), here are some of those that might find your interest

> $('#fileupload')
>   ...
>   .bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
>
>   .bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
>
>   .bind('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
>
>   ...
>
>   .bind('fileuploadprocessdone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})